# Google play The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, google-play-console, android-keystore

I used the same key to sign the apps and yet I get

The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version.

This which I checked:

- Keystore is same
- Password, alias etc same
- Packagename and appname same
- Release build, no debug/test flag

I compared the signatures of the existing app from google play console and the new app using

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile existing.apk
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile new.apk
```

and the `SHA1, MD5 and SHA256` are identical. 
Yet the error. What else am i missing?

Comment: Are you enrolled in App Signing by Play? Did you reset your upload key recently by any chance?

Comment: no, not enrolled, also, haven't reset anything.

Comment: When you run the command to print the certificate, did you use the "existing.apk" downloaded from Play Console? If not, I would suggest that you do that to make sure that it's effectively the one that you uploaded in your first version.

Comment: yes, existing.apk was downloaded from store, new.apk was the one I wanted to submit

Comment: Something does not add up here. If the APK you upload to the Play Console has the same certificate sha1 as the previous one uploaded, then there is no reason this shouldn't work. The error message should display the certificate fingerprint that you uploaded vs the one that is expected (which should correspond to the certificate of existing.apk)